# Is it possible to get cancer after taking iron supplement of 100mg for 4 days

Tags: cancer, health-informatics, iron, iron-supplements, colon

I took iron supplements of 100mg ferrous ascorbate for 4 days but since day 3 I experienced black stools and strange pain during bowel movement plus got hemorrhoids so I stopped it immediately after day 4. My hemorrhoids subsided after stopping the pills.

This was about a month ago but now when I google I read some linkage between iron supplement and cancer https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/321515.php

Can I get colon cancer after taking supplements for just 4 days? I read symptoms of colon cancer and one of them is constipation I experience constipation once in a while but no blood in stools.

Screening for cancer is very expensive. From your experience do you think cancer could likely have happened during those 4 days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Side effects of iron supplements](https://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/iron-supplement-oral-route-parenteral-route/side-effects/drg-20070148) can include:

- Black stools
- Constipation
- Abdominal pain

So, these are common side effects that have nothing to do with cancer.

In the study described in [Medical News Today](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/321515.php), they did not confirmed the  cause-effect relationship between iron supplements and cancer, because they only found a substance (a marker) that could be associated with cancer, and it was a laboratory study and not a study on humans.